# NSIS RadioButton !insertmacro RadioGetChecked

Tags: radio-button, nsis

In Nsis I try to use RadioButton for Sections. First I try to compile the code from the example:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/RadioButtons

But I get the error at this line

`!insertmacro RadioGetChecked "${g1o1}" "${g1o1},${g1o2},${g1o3}"`

error message:

`!insertmacro: macro named "RadioGetChecked" not found!`

Whats wrong? I just copied the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy and paste the Macros section on that page, those macros need to exist before the functions in the script.

Comment: Thats not realy clear, if you have to add the macro to your script or not. Because the macro SectionRadioButtons already exists. And its working without adding the macros below the excample.

Comment: If !insertmacro says it can't find a macro then the macro is missing or placed too far down in the script.

Comment: yes thats clear. but i dont understand why nsis knows the macro "SectionRadioButtons". Without adding this macro. But it does not know the macro RadioGetChecked.

So why is the macro SectionRadioButtons includes somewhere in the nsis software and why do I have to copy the macro RadioGetChecked.

This is also not described in the example.

Comment: It is not included anywhere in NSIS, you must have copied it yourself from that page or you are using a 3rd-party nsh file.

Comment: Sorry. It is included, at least SectionRadioButtons. This macro is working withoud adding it to my script!

Comment: I'm telling you that is not possible, check the nsh files and your nsi.

Comment: If I create a new nsi file only with the code of the example and the macros so the first error I get is:
!macro: macro named "StartRadioButtons" already exists!

Comment: So .. how to run this example in my Test.nsi file so it works? What to remove what to add?